# Android Custom View at Runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanna pass parameter to Custom View at runtime.
is that possible?

```
 <custom.analog.clock.AnalogClock1 
        android:id="@+id/clock"  
        style="@style/clock"  
        analoge:isALive="1"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible

Just use traditional way:

```
AnalogClock1 mClock = (AnalogClock1)this.findViewById(R.id.clock);
mClock.setAnyValue(value);
```

and don't forget to `import` the `AnalogClock1` in your class.